# FSharp.Data ResolutionFolder for multiple xsd throws FS1109

Tags: xml, f#, xsd, f#-data

I am trying to use the XmlTypeProvider to create the type using an xsd structure.
I have fired up VS2017 and saved a new fsx file in my awesome scripts folder. In the same folder I have a packages folder that contains the version 3.3.3 of FSharp.Data.
Loading the dll and opening it works as expected.

In my case, I have 3 xsd docs that have a hierarchy. I have placed them in them all in one folder names XSD next to the fsx file. When trying to create a type from either of those xsds, everything is OK. I get the type, intellisense, the whole lot.

Reading the [docs](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html), suggests to use the ResolutionFolder parameter if there are *other schema files* (couldn't really tell by that *other* if it means hierarchy-related or simply more than one).

If I try to create a type using the following syntax:

```
type Reconciliation = XmlProvider<ResolutionFolder = @"...\XSD", Schema=@"...\grandpa.xsd">
```

I get the following error:

```
error FS1109: A refererence to the type
FSharp.Data.XmlProvider, ResolutionFolder="sameValue",Schema="sameValue"
in assembly FSharp.Data was found
but the type could not be found in that assembly.
```

Trying the other xsd files was, as expected, futile.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this using VS2019. I have two .xsd files, one of which includes the other. The `ResolutionFolder` successfully identifies their location. The only significant difference between my code and yours is that I'm using `#r "nuget: FSharp.Data"` rather than a `packages` folder to load the type provider assembly. (I also have to reference `System.Xml.Linq`) I did see one similar (but quite old) bug report here: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data/issues/57#issuecomment-164690733

Comment: I get the same error using VS2019. @brianberns I tried `#r "nuget: FSharp.Data"` in F# interactive and still get the same error.

Comment: Can you create a small example that reproduces the problem? Maybe upload it as a GitHub repository so we can debug.

Comment: @brianberns I figured out what's causing this issue. If I put backslash at the end of `ResolutionFolder` path this error appears. (eg: `ResolutionFolder = @"C:\someFolder\"`) If I remove backslash (eg: `ResolutionFolder = @"C:\someFolder"`) error goes away.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm glad you figured it out!